# FORMATMESSAGE with a TAB character

Tags: sql, string, tabs, character, formatmessage

I have recently learned about the FORMATMESSAGE (link below) and I have started using it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186788.aspx

I have aware that I have print/select a TAB character (link below) but I would like to learn how to you it inside the FROMATMESSAGE function
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx

I have tried using CHAR(9) and the escape character \t but it looks like it does not like it.

I know there are workarounds and it will not be hard for me to think of an alternative way outside of using FORMATMESSAGE but I was really curious about it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies but I have actaully found out my own answer.

Altough the escape character does not work but CHAR(9) works fine.

To see the results to have to change your results output to "Results To Text" (Ctrl + t).

You cannot see such non printable characters inside a Grid (Ctrl + D).